# Moving elements between two std::vectors which are using different allocators

Tags: c++, vector, move, allocator

I have an object of type `std::vector<a_trivially_copiable_type, my_custom_allocator>`. At some point, I need to inject this into a 3rd-party-library which accepts only a `std::vector<a_trivially_copiable_type>`. For my use case it is fine that from that point on `my_custom_allocator` won't be used anymore. What is not fine, is that the `std::vector` content is at any moment duplicated in the process.

So I tried to do this:

```
auto tmp = std::vector<a_trivially_copiable_type>{};
tmp = std::move(the_vector_with_the_custom_allocator);
auto library_obj = ThirdPartyLibraryObject{std::move(tmp)};
```

But this does not work since the STL requires the two `std::vector` to have exactly the same type. Also, `std::move` in `<algorithm>` does not help since it will only move the objects of type `a_trivially_copiable_type`, which will result in nothing better than a `std::memcpy` since they are trivially copiable.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of [pmr containers/allocators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator)?

Comment: If you don't want to copy the elements, then that means the elements are still in storage managed by the original allocator. The new vector has to know which allocator to use to free that memory when it eventually cleans up. `std::vector<T>` will use `std::vector` expects that allocator to be a `std::allocator` which isn't the case.

Comment: if the container is too big that you can't have 2 copies of it then the best option is to not use a vector, instead use a highly fragmented container, that you can copy and delete part by part.

Comment: hum, I probably didn't think enough about the ```move``` part. I'm not sure at all that ```pmr``` can be applied with ```move```.

Comment: Why not do `std::vector<a_trivially_copiable_type> tmp(std::begin(the_vector_with_the_custom_allocator), std::end(the_vector_with_the_custom_allocator));`?   You won't be able to get away with simply moving all the elements of `the_vector_with_the_custom_allocator` into `tmp` since, presumably, memory allocated with your custom allocator should not be released by the standard allocator (and vice versa).

Comment: @Oersted the problem is that also pmr changes the type of the std::vector to std::pmr::vector

Comment: @Peter in general it would be the case, but my allocator is redirecting to new and delete and it is used to only collec statistics / logging / this type of things

Comment: the idea of pmr is to use only pmr containers, not mixing both kinds. Yet I don't think it can work with move (I didn't pratice these libraries yet)

Comment: No, there is no way to achieve this.